# T-SQL Filter on dynamic columns

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

This has probably been asked before, but it's such a complicated topic I'm having trouble getting my head around it. So thought I'd ask specifics.

I have the following "CampaignCalls" table, e.g.:

```
ID | contactName | contactNumber
1  | Joe Bloggs  | 123456789
2  | Simon Smith | 456987321
3  | Jane Doe    | 852936414
```

In addition I have the one-to-many table of "custom columns" that are user-defined, "CampaignCall_Fields", e.g.:

```
ID | fieldName
1  | Company
2  | Alternative Number
3  | Address 1 
4  | Address 2
```

And an intersect table that defines each corresponding value for the custom column ("CampaignCall_Field_values"), e.g.:

```
CampaignCall_ID | field_ID | value
1               | 1        | ACME
1               | 2        | 789456123
1               | 3        | 123 Fake St
1               | 4        | London
2               | 1        | Initech
2               | 2        | 789456123
2               | 3        | 456 Fake St
2               | 4        | Paris
3               | 1        | Greendale
3               | 2        | 789456123
3               | 3        | 789 Fake St
3               | 4        | New York City
```

I have an application that is supposed to be able to display, to users, a report of all the rows, such as in the format below:

```
Name        | Number    | Company | Address 1   | Address 2
Joe Bloggs  | 123456789 | ACME    | 123 Fake St | London
Simon Smith | 456987321 | Initech | 456 Fake St | Paris
```

But I also want to give users the capability to create filters, on any of the columns specified in this example, e.g. a user can say "only return rows where Name = Joe Bloggs AND Company = ACME".

**CURRENTLY** I am doing this by pulling through all data (filtered accordingly) from the "CampaignCalls" table, and then, in PHP, iterating through all returned rows and fetching the data from the "CampaignCall_Field_values" table (filtered accordingly), and then pivoting the data into the main array (if not all the data is returned, I know that a filter has "filtered out" that row and the row is removed from the array).

This is very inefficient as it takes a long time and opens a different database connection for each row. So I am looking to see if there is a way of reducing the number of database connections and/or the complexity of the algorithm.

I am looking to do this ideally by somehow create some database view that contains all the dynamic fields, with appropriate indexes etc. and then running the report against that. This seems the cleanest way, but not sure how I would dynamically create such a view. Also not sure as the performance implications of this.

Could someone provide any insight or opinion on how to implement this solution, or an alternative, better solution? I've been pulling my hair out here to create a stable, efficient solution, and I can't believe it's never been done before. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is exactly why the EAV model is considered an SQL anti-pattern. It does of course have its place within RDBMS design, but unless you have a great number of frequently changing attributes, it is usually better to adopt the relational design. I won't say too much more as I don't want to spark debate, there are 26,100 results for a google search of [SQL EAV vs Relational](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=SQL+EAV+vs+relational), I don't think I can say anything that has not already been said.

Comment: Okay well I've never actually heard of EAV... glad to know what I'm doing has a name! How would I reorganise this into a Relational pattern (not sure what you mean by relational in this context)? Or is that too big for a single comment....

Comment: In the relational model you would not have the table `CampaignCall_Field_values`, instead you would just have additional columns on `CampaignCalls`. So your table is already in the structure you are trying to achieve. As I said, there are so many articles about this on the internet, there is nothing more I can add. I'd suggest picking one and reading up on the pros and cons of each method.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I had a quick read of your link and a few articles and have my head around it now - just wondered on your opinion on how you would alter the schema. Thanks!

Comment: If this is exactly the kind of question you're trying to avoid feel free to ignore it - but since the custom values here are dynamic (user controlled, variable number of them) would this not constitute altering the schema in live production? Which I always thought was a bad thing?

Comment: If the variables are user controlled then yes, it is a problem, and Entity-attribute-value is the only way to proceed, but you should then also be aware that the format you are trying to export to is probably not fit for purpose, you could end up with a report with 1,000s of columns, which is going to take a long time to generate, and be of little or no use once it has generated.  How many variables are you expecting to end up with and how frequently will they be added?

Comment: Probably at most about 30, and they probably will rarely change. I'm leaning towards an option of a hybrid model, where there are, say, 50 generically-identified columns in the CampaignCall table and the user just identifies each one as they wish. I'm currently looking into the implications of doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

First `join` the three tables to get relevant data then use `pivot` to get the required format

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT contactName,
               value,
               fieldName
        FROM   CampaignCalls C
               JOIN CampaignCall_Field_values CF
                 ON c.ID = cf.CampaignCall_ID
               JOIN [custom columns] Cs
                 ON cs.ID = cf.field_ID)A
       PIVOT (Max(value)
             FOR fieldname IN ([Company],
                               [Alternative Number],
                               [Address 1],
                               [Address 2]))piv
```

**Update:** If you don't know the `fields` then use `Dynamic Pivot`

```
DECLARE @sql  NVARCHAR(max),
        @cols VARCHAR(max)

SET @cols = (SELECT DISTINCT Quotename(fieldName) + ','
             FROM   [custom columns]
             FOR xml path(''))

SELECT @cols = LEFT(@cols, Len(@cols) - 1)

SET @sql='SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT contactName,
               value,
               fieldName
        FROM   CampaignCalls C
               JOIN CampaignCall_Field_values CF
                 ON c.ID = cf.CampaignCall_ID
               JOIN [custom columns] Cs
                 ON cs.ID = cf.field_ID)A
       PIVOT (Max(value)
             FOR fieldname IN (' + @cols
         + '))piv '

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Okay, bu the issue is I don't know what the dynamic fields would be. Is there a way of dynamically running this PIVOT?

Comment: @Raiden616 - Updated check now

Comment: Oh I see, never mind. I've got it working thanks so much - except it takes a long long time. Is there anything I can do to make this more efficient? Especially since I have to put this in a view and then query ON it.

Comment: @Raiden616 - No you cannot use Dynamic queries inside view. Try to make it as a `SP`

Comment: Okay - question. If I somehow scheduled this stored procedure to run and populate a table with the results of this every 10 minutes, and then pulled a report from that, would that be bad practice? I'd have to dynamically determine the columns...

Answer (score 0):

Although I have suggested moving away from EAV in comments I will nevertheless try to assist with the problem it has brought. I would suggest applying any filter before you pivot the data, in order to do this effectively you will first need to create a new type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringPair AS TABLE
(
    Value1 NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    Value2 NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);
```

This is to hold the pairs needed for your filter (field name, and field value), then you can create a stored procedure that takes this as a paramter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetCampaignCalls @Filter dbo.StringPair READONLY
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(FieldName)
                                        FROM CampaignCall_Fields
                                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    WITH CampaignCallFields AS
    (   SELECT  cc.ID,
                cc.contactName,
                cc.contactNumber,
                f.FieldName,
                v.Value
        FROM    CampaignCalls AS cc
                INNER JOIN CampaignCall_Field_values AS v
                    ON cc.ID = v.CampaignCall_ID
                INNER JOIN CampaignCall_Fields AS f
                    ON f.ID = v.field_ID
    )
    SELECT  pvt.*
    FROM    (   SELECT  *
                FROM    CampaignCallFields AS c
                WHERE   EXISTS
                        (   SELECT  1
                            FROM    CampaignCallFields AS c2
                                    INNER JOIN @Filter AS f
                                        ON f.Value1 = c2.FieldName
                                        AND f.Value2 = c2.Value
                            WHERE   c2.ID = c.ID
                            GROUP BY c2.ID
                            HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Filter)
                        )
            ) AS c
            PIVOT 
            (   MAX(Value)
                FOR FieldName IN (' + @Cols + ')
            ) AS pvt;';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Filter dbo.StringPair READONLY', @Filter;
END
```

This would then be called as:

```
DECLARE @Filter dbo.StringPair;
INSERT @Filter VALUES ('Company', 'ACME');
EXECUTE dbo.GetCampaignCalls @Filter;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a17f/2)**

I think what you have alluded to in a comment could be the way forward, you should certainly be storing as many core fields as you can in the main table, like you have done with contactNumber and contactName, then just use the attribute table for outlying fields that may be added on the fly.